# Can't login to my profile after a change in the ProfileImagePath

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, user-profiles, regedit

I'm on windows 10 and I entered the registry and changed the `ProfileImagePath`'s value

As soon as I had done that, my pc broke, couldn't access files and not even the start menu.

I restaarted it and then when it prompts me for my PIN, i log in but only as a temporary user.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: “How can I fix this?” - Revert your changes, since your changes, appear directly responsible for the behavior you describe

Comment: I did, and it's not working.

Comment: See if you can make a new Windows User Account (Start, Settings, Accounts).  Make it a member of Administrators. Log into the new account and see if the new Account works properly. If not, you will likely have to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: @Amrou - Edit your question to include that information and the current value of the key. *Please don't reinstall Windows to solve this problem.* Reinstalling Windows to fix such a simple problem is overkill.